# SEO strategy for dynamic images ( PHP + GD )

Tags: seo, php, sitemap, images

I have several images which are generated by using PHP + GD. They consist of a background image, and colored lines drawn on top of the images.

As the possible combinations depend on the behaviour of the final user, this must necessarily be a dynamic method of providing the images.

The URL would then be: `www.example.com/image.php?param1=value1&param2=value2&...&paramN=valueN`

How would it affect SEO if I try to make an Image-Sitemap of several of the most rendered images?

Should I save the images in a static format, something like `SEO-Friendly-Name-Derived-from-parameters.png` or Google and other search engines did not care about the image file not existing at all (first case) and would use the alt and title parameters ?

**Note**: these generated images are all hight quality images, because they are simply the diagram of components of the product. With each piece which is important (seo name of the file) highlited in other color. That means thousand of combinations of images, which I can, in any case, draw once with PHP + GD + Mysql and store as physical files.

Comment: What value do these generated images provide to searchers?   Do they have keywords associated with them?   Google images algorithm prefers "high quality" images.   That generally means full color, photographic images in large sizes.    Unless your images are going to be relevant for users searching for specific things, it probably isn't worth your time to try to get them into image search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

having a static image's url / path would help your image to appear in image search results.

without having an image url it can't be cached properly.

yes, i would strongly recommend to use images like images, making use of real image files and implement them with img src alt + title or css.

Comment: What I don't understand is why there is a difference in `example.com/views.php?name=component_1_of_engine&brand=Whatelse&model=futuristic` with component_1_of_engine_Whatelse_uturistic.jpg. In fact, the first one gives more information, and the HTTP headers can be identical, with all the attrb tags available, as it is called in the same way    <img src="example.com/views.php?blablabla=blabla" />